# Unit test for C++ win32 application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have to write unit tests for C++ win32 console application developed on visual studio 2010.

- Previously I wrote some unit test for a C++ DLL by adding dereference to test project.
- But as you know cannot reference win32 exe files to test project.

So how can I use the 'methods in my project' inside the test project? I tired by adding whole project as reference. but not success. 
please some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new project and add there source files of the code that you are planning to test. This means that for your testing you will have only executable that will contain both your dev and your test code.

Other way (not really recommended) is injecting test DLL into the process and looking for entry points into the destination code from inside this dll.

Comment: Actual what I did was first created my project(`calculator`) and secondly added a new test project(`calculator_test`) to the same solution. Then I added a reference to `calculator` from `calculator_test`. but when I try to write `[TestMethod]` method, `calculator` project or classes in that project not accessible to `calculator_test` project. could you refer more explanation, example or tutorial about how to write unit test for C++ applications (not for LIB or DLL)?

Comment: Solution is just a set of binaries. Every binary lives with its own life. I advise you not to use terms solution and reference. They are too Windows specific. They are not used in the bigger C/C++ world.

Comment: When you link a binary, you pick up code from .obj files and libraries. Read about libraries and especially about DLL input libraries. Try to create separate solutions for each binary. This will help you to understand how the whole system works.